# css: ie shifts button's text value and background

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, submit

I've got a submit button in a list:

```
    <ul>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Pls don't shift" /></li>
    </ul>
```

- The li and the input have different backgrounds, and these should be positionable.
- The input should have dynamic width (depending on the value).
- The input's value should be almost at the input's bottom.

These things reduce the number of opportunities to solve the problem.

And the problem exactly is: IE8 and IE9 shift the text of value, and IE8 shifts the background too.

I've tried to solve it and made this css (this is only a 'debug-css'):

```
    li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    input,
    input:active:hover {
    display: block;
    background: url(tools-48x48.png)  no-repeat center center;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visble;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 2px;
}
input:active:hover {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And the most interesting thing is: Now if I click on the button's text value, then it makes the same bad shift, but if I click eslewhere (on the button, but not on the text value) then it works.

That was the point when I've minded to write here.
How to disable submit buttons :active state in IE?

Thank you!

Comment: I have this problem too, and it's been making me CRAZY!  I trust you found this http://haslayout.net/css/Button-Background-Shift-On-active-Bug - which doesn't even mention the text value aspect?

Comment: I have made this Fiddle according to your code http://jsfiddle.net/f67Vw/ So if im correct the main issue is that the text shift 1px down and 1px right when I click and hold the mouse down over the text?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this in IE9 and when I remove several styles that "aren't" used the input text doesn't shift when you click on it.

removed styles:

```
li {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
input,
input:active:hover{
    background: url(tools-48x48.png) no-repeat center center;
    outline:none;
}
```

and added the styles

```
input,
input:active:hover{
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;

}
```

See my Fiddle for more details here: http://jsfiddle.net/f67Vw/4/

A good other option seems to be to replace it with a carefully styled `a` element.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="button">Doesn't shift</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 19px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Again see my Fiddle for more details here: http://jsfiddle.net/f67Vw/4/

Comment: Sorry but IE8 shifts text as well as background. You have to add some image to it to observe the shifting effect of the background: http://jsfiddle.net/f67Vw/43/

Comment: I'm using IE9 and your first example (the actual button) has the text shifting around. :(